# Meet Error when run Spring MVC web application, " Servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in web application threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: eclipse, spring, web-services, model-view-controller, web

Hello I was trying to build a simple spring MVC project but when I am running my code I am getting: Hello I am new to spring and I was trying to build a simple spring MVC project but when I am running my code I am getting: Servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in web application threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I run it in Eclipse + TomCAt 9.0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing some jar(s). Note the specific class that you're missing, then google the jar that it belongs in, download it and add it to your project.